# <Cointegration> Quant model with Econometrics

Tags: statistics, economics

I'm designing a quant model, and wondering whether it is possible to contain two cointegration tests?
The design of the quant trading model is:

Test the stationarity through ***Augmented Dickey Fuller*** test,

1) just leave a time series (price data of a stock) if it is I(0) process, and because it is stationary, then test this through Augmented Dickey Fuller Cointegration test, or

2) If a time series is I(1) process, which means non-stationary, then put it through the ***Engle Granger test*** (which tests two combination of non-stationary time series)

---

if any of my logic is incorrect or wrong, please let me know. I am in a desperate need.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Maybe this question is not intended to be placed on stackoverflow? Personally as a programmer I don't fully understand 80% of the information in this question.

Comment: This is an academic subject behind the technical stuff of programming. And I thought people here would have an idea on this theme

Comment: Data structures? Algorithms? Standard libraries? Performance optimization? IDE? if no, then I think not this site. Try to search more here: http://stackexchange.com/sites#science

Comment: You can refer to the python statsmodel package for all your questions on the usage of econometrics statistical tests.